# Is it ok to eliminate the "I" in informal English (e.g. "Am sorry" vs "I am sorry")?

Tags: sentence-starts, subject-drop

I have seen writing where "I" is being dropped in sentences. For instance, "Am on my way" vs. "I am on my way". Is this acceptable usage?

Comment: What happens (outside of chat) is the _contraction_ "**I'm** on my way." But in chat or text, you might as well elide both "I" and "am":  **On my way** (or, if you like, **OMW**).

Answer (score 0):

"I" is dropped usually when we are writing a conversation or speech.
Formally when we write, "I" should not be dropped.
In the example you have shown,

"Am on my way" can be from a conversation. But When you are writing in an official way "I am on my way" has to be used.

Comment: The same way, *you* should not be abbreviated to *u* in formal writing. Do not use chat lingo on ELU.